# git reset --hard is not making my local files match origin, despite HEAD pointing to the latest commit

Tags: git, github

I don't understand git as well as I thought I did.

My goal was to pull from my remote branch, but when I did that, my local files did not match up with what is on my remote branch.

I ran

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/XX
```

My understanding is that git should have pulled from origin/XX, and threw away all of my local changes to be able to match my local files to that of origin/XX

However, my local files are not updated to match origin/XX.

I see `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/XX'.` and git pull reiterates that I'm already up to date. `git log` shows that I'm pointed to XX.

I know that I can delete everything and re-clone the repo, but I'd ideally like to avoid that, as I have files that I would need to manually move over to the cloned repo if I redo it all.

Would someone happen to know what I'm missing? I feel like I'm very close to having a solution, but my understanding is not quite there yet.

Comment: What kind of differences are we talking about?

Comment: Files in the remote repository aren't shown in my local repo. Existing files also dont have code changes. I have also tried cloning the whole repo to no avail. Lastly, I tried to git reset --hard to an earlier spot and then git fetch --all, and git merge, and I see the files that I want coming in. However, the files don't exist on my system.

Comment: Does `git status` output a clean working tree? Are you runing your git commands from the repo's root?

Comment: After some grueling debugging using turtoise git to track where files and code changes could have possibly disappeared to, I found the problem. I'm embarrassed to say that I tricked myself into thinking I was looking at the right directory, but there was another directory that had a very similar pathname and I was opening my vs code using the wrong directory as root, so any changes were "invisible" to me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and we've all been there :)